# Django - Using multiple databases, one for each client

Tags: django, django-models, database-design, django-rest-framework, database-connection

I am building a companion web/mobile application for an existing web app. The database is implemented in MySQL. I will be writing an API using Django/Django Rest Framework (DRF).

The application is used by various organizations. The interesting part about the implementation is that each organization has it's own database. In the existing web application, the user enters the database name along with the login credentials.

How to go about implementing this in Django? I am going to have lots of models - and they all need to read from the correct database depending on the current user.

Answer (score -1):

in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'database_one': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'USER': 'db1_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db1_pwd'
    },
    'database_two': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db2',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'USER': 'db2_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db2_pwd'
    }
}
```

For sync your database, you should do like this:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py migrate --database=database_one
python manage.py migrate --database=database_two
```

The first command operates on the default database, and with the --database option you can operate the database you want.

More info. can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/